# Set Slackbot a reminder for every weekday except Wednesday

Tags: slack, slack-commands

I'm looking for something like

```
/remind @channel "It's time for daily stand up !" Monday Tuesday Thursday Friday at 11:45am. Click here to join: Link.
```

Answer (score 8):

```
/remind @channel "It's time for daily stand up !" every Monday and Tuesday and Thursday and Friday
```

Answer (score 2):

You have many possibilities.

Example (implicit, *weekday*):

```
/remind @channel "It's time for daily stand up!" every weekday
```

or (long way, day list):

```
/remind @channel "It's time for daily stand up!" every Monday and Tuesday and Wednesday and Thursday and Friday
```

and you can also add a specific time, for example:

```
/remind @channel "It's time for daily stand up!" at 9AM every weekday
```

Docs:
https://slack.com/intl/en-gb/help/articles/208423427-Set-a-reminder